I have a wordpress form created in PHP, and I cannot get it to exectue the ajax and return
I have a form and ajax email validation that works outside of wordpress. When I try to migrate into wordpress it's not validating if the email exists in the database.
This is what I have in my functions.php file
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_validate_email', 'email_validation');

function email_validation()

{

global $wpdb; // Use the global $wpdb object

    `{`

        `error_reporting(E_ALL);` 

        `$email = $_POST['Email'];`

        `$emailclean = explode('@', $email);`

        `$domain = array_pop($emailclean);`

        `$bad_domains = array('gmail.com','hotmail.com');` 



        `#$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","site");`

        `$sql = $wpdb->prepare("Select count(*) from" .$wpdb->prefix . "EmailValidation where email ='$email'");`

        `$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);`



        `#$query = mysqli_query($link, "Select * from Users where email ='$email'");`

        `if(count($results)>0)`
{

#$error="<span class = 'text-danger'> email exists, please login</span>";

echo "<span style='color:red'> It appears you are already a member, please contact us at  for futher assistance. </span>";

echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',true);</script>";

}

        `elseif (in_array($domain, $bad_domains) ) {`
echo "<span style='color:red'> Please register with your personal email </span>";

echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',true);</script>";

        `}`





        `else`

        `{`
echo 'Thank You for becoming a member';

echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',false);</script>";

        `}`



    `}`



`}`

I have this in the web page
<script>

setTimeout(function(){ callAjax(); }, 3000);

function checkemail() {

jQuery.ajax({

url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",

data: {'Email='+$("#Email").val(), action: 'email_validation'},

type: "POST",

success:function(data){

setTimeout(function(){

$("#check-email").html(data);

},3000);

},

error:function (){}

});

}

</script>

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Email portion of the form
<div class = "form-group container-fluid">

<label for="Registrant" class="inlineEditor">Email</label>

<div class="row ">

<div class="col" >

<input type="email" required class="form-control checking_email" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder= "ex@example.com"oninput="checkemail()" style="background-color:rgb(248, 250, 251);"/>

<small id="FirstName" class="text-muted">

</small>

<div class="invalid-feedback"> Please provide a valid email address.

</div>

<span id="check-email"></span>

</div>

</div>

</div>


The $sql variable is missing a whitespace after from,  here: "Select count(*) from". Otherwise it will create something like Select count(*) fromDATABASEPREFIX ... resulting in a query with a syntax error. By the way, that's not a prepared query, even if you use prepare.

To write less confusing code you can declare the table name in a variable: $table=$wpdb->prefix."EmailValidation; And on the other hand, write a real prepared query, using markers and passing in the second parameter of prepare the value or values ​​that would correspond to the markers: $sql = $wpdb->prepare("Select count(*) from $table where email = %s",[$email]); For more details, please see the documentation.

Thank you that fixed it! Silly mistake the white space.

The $sql variable is missing a whitespace after from, it will create something like Select count(*) fromDATABASEPREFIX ... resulting in a query with a syntax error. By the way, that's not a prepared query, even if you use prepare.
To write less confusing code you can declare the table name in a variable and  write a real prepared query, using markers and passing in the second parameter of prepare the value or values ​​that would correspond to the markers:
$table=$wpdb->prefix."EmailValidation";
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("Select count(*) from $table where email = %s",[$email]); 

For more details, please see the documentation.
